# SQL SERVER - Convert String em Dias

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como posso converter essa string em dias?

Exemplo: retornar "2 dias e 2 hrs"?

```
SELECT '50:00:00'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando a resposta do Ricardo e resolvendo o caso de haver mais de 99 horas na string de entrada ficaria assim:

```
declare @h int, @m int, @s int, @time varchar(8), @pos int
set @time = '155:00:00'
set @pos = CHARINDEX( ':', @time )
set @h = SUBSTRING(@time, 1, @pos-1)
set @m = SUBSTRING(@time, @pos+1, 2)
set @s = SUBSTRING(@time, @pos+4, 2)

select cast (@h/24 as nvarchar(10)) + 'dias, ' + cast (@h%24 as nvarchar(10)) + 'horas, ' + cast (@m as nvarchar(2)) + 'minutos, ' + cast (@s as nvarchar(2)) + 'segundos'
```

Comment: uma outra solução, se estiver usando o **SQL Server 2016** é usar a function `STRING_SPLIT` no lugar do `CHARINDEX` para separar os valores: [STRING_SPLIT](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3):

Divida '50' por 24 e você vai ter o número de dias.
Pegue o resto da divisão de '50' por 24 e vai ter o restante das horas.
Os minutos e segundos não precisa calcular.

```
declare @h int, @m int, @s int, @time varchar(8)
set @time = '50:00:00'
set @h = SUBSTRING(@time, 1, 2)
set @m = SUBSTRING(@time, 4, 2)
set @s = SUBSTRING(@time, 7, 2)

select cast (@h/24 as nvarchar(10)) + 'dias, ' + cast (@h%24 as nvarchar(10)) + 'horas, ' + cast (@m as nvarchar(2)) + 'minutos, ' + cast (@s as nvarchar(2)) + 'segundos'
```

Veja um exemplo aqui: [http://sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/25741)

Comment: Porém tem restrições com valores maiores que 99 horas.

Comment: Sim, bem observado, acho que fazer o *split* da string usando ":" como separador ajude a evitar isso